# Realizar Chamadas / Enviar SMS entre emuladores Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Usando o *AVD Manager*, criei dois dispositivos - um com **API level 22** e outro com **API level 23**.

Carregando os dois dispositivos com o emulador, gostaria de realizar chamadas e enviar SMS de um para o outro.

O emulador **API 22** está na porta `5554`.

O emulador **API 23** está na porta `5556`.

Tentei discar e enviar mensagem de um para o outro usando a porta de cada um, mas não obtive sucesso.

Só para constar, consigo simular ligações e envio de mensagens usando o próprio emulador, mas pra ele próprio, não de um para o outro.

Estou usando Windows 10 e Android Studio.

Alguém já passou por isso?